# laravel email verification won't send

Tags: php, laravel

I have custom register controller in laravel 5.8 and it returns:

> Cannot send message without a sender address

## Code

`Controller`

```
public function newRegisterSend(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ));

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
            'first_login' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);
        $profile = new Profile;
        $profile->user_id = $user->id;
        $profile->save();

        $user->assignRole('non-employee');
        $user->changee()->insert([
            'changeable_id' => $user->id,
            'changeable_type' => 'App\User',
            'creator_id' => $user->id,
            'updator_id' => null,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification(); // sending verification email
        return $user;
}
```

`route`

```
Auth::routes([ 'register' => false, 'verify' => true ]);
```

`user model`

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {
  //...
}
```

`.env`

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=MyApp
```

Any idea?

Comment: Run `php artisan tinker` and output `config('mail')`. Check that everything there is correct.

Comment: @ceejayoz here is screenshot of result https://ibb.co/hRcFmWg

Comment: @ceejayoz i cached my configs and now it's working :) Thank you

Comment: Hooray! Glad that pointed you in the right direction.